# Cant get the legend to show correctly on the chart

Tags: python-3.x

my legend is showing top right, but rather then stating AAPL and IBM it says one letter. cant figure out whats wrong

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_mean_volume(symbol):
    df = quandl.get("YAHOO/"+str(symbol))[::-1]
    return df[['High', 'Adjusted Close']]


stock = ['AAPL', 'IBM']

for s in stock:
    plt.plot(get_mean_volume(s))
    plt.legend(s)
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the matplotlib.legend() documentation.

> To make a legend for lines which already exist on the axes (via plot
>   for instance), simply call this function with an iterable of strings,
>   one for each legend item. For example:

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.legend(['A simple line'])
```

You should probably also add a `plt.show()`.

So since you dont use any labels I think you should use:

```
plt.legend([s])
```

The error that you only see one letter is probably caused by the fact that legend iterates over the input (s="AAPL") and takes the first item (s[0]) for the label text for line 1 (s[0] is 'A').
For the second iteration of the loop the same happens for the 'I' (Because s[0]='I' in this case. s[1](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) = 'B' and so on... )

`legend()` seems pretty customizable just check the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend).

So this is the result for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stock = ['AAPL']

for s in stock:
    plt.plot([1,2,3])
    plt.legend([s])
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image]